# MySQL calculated field good practice

Tags: mysql

I have two tables like below :

[image: ERD]

I just would like to know if it is a good practice to use this structure and put the sum of all the invoices amount on the parent table in order to get faster requests and avoid some recurrent calculation (the result will be updated with a trigger after on the invoices table)?

Or is it better to get a normalized table and do not caching the kind of calculated fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not bad practice *per se*.
However, you should think twice before implementing it. Denormalization may improve performance, but not always, and it also has a cost in term of maintainability.

On average, how many <strike>subprojects</strike> invoices exist for each project? If only a handful, then the cost of calculating the total is negligible. Do not denormalize in this case.

For one given project, how often is the list of <strike>subprojects</strike> invoices likely to change? If very rarely, then you should probably pre-caclulate the total.

Conversely, if the list of <strike>subprojects</strike> invoices is likely to change "often" (compared to the frequency at which you will need  read/calculate the sum), then you are likely to spend more time re-calculating the sums than necessary.

Bottomline: do not denormalize before you identify a bottleneck in the real. It should be relatively painless to rewrite your application to account for the refactoring at a later time, once you identify a real performance issue.

Comment: Basically a project won't contain more than 20 subproject and a subproject not many more than 10 invoices. But the select calculation will be more frequent than the update because the subproject will be opened from a table list that will contain this sum column. Furthermore a validated invoice will not be editable anymore. But with your explanation I think it is not a good idea to implement this calculated field until I can find a real low performance. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with storing the totals using the given structure. You have `invoice_number` and `invoice_date` to use as keys so there's no danger of confusion. Only calculating once obviously is more efficient. Basically, why do the calculations every time a result is needed?

Comment: Thank you, It's exactly what I thought but I just wanted to be sure that's not a bad practice. For example, if any person edit the database manually and don't update the total on the parent table it would create an integrity error (`invoiced_sell_price_DF` will no longer been equal to the sum of `invoice_total_DF`. But the trigger should avoid this problem. After I read some web blog talking about normalization forms we just become parano!